# Getting xml and xmf files into blender

Tags: mesh

I'm new to blender a bit and I'm trying to find a way to import xmf/xml files into it. Is there plug in I can use to be able to edit the models inside of blender?

Comment: Aka xdmf http://www.xdmf.org/index.php/Read_Xdmf ?

Comment: Given you are below the rep needed to comment , if this is the spec you are after you can edit your question accordingly.